# How to add attribute class in theme('pager') in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, pagination

How to add attribute class in theme('pager') in drupal 7 ?

my code is following:

```
$directory_table .= theme('pager', array('quantity', $STAFF_COUNT ),array(
'element' => array(
            'class' => array('pagination pull-right'))));
```

but it is not applying the class to the pager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) function only expects 1 parameter (an array of variables), so your theme function call should look like this:

```
$directory_table .= theme('pager', array('quantity' => $STAFF_COUNT, 'element' => array('class' => array('pagination pull-right'))));
```

BUT:
It seems that [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) just sets a 'pager' class ignoring any variables which you may send to the function.

So, your best bet is to just override the [theme_pager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager/7) function. Do this by just copying it to your themes template.php file and renaming the function to MYTHEME_pager. Then you can just add the classes you need in that function, Or add the logic you need to add the classes depending on a variable sent to the function.

Remember to clear the theme cache after overriding the function.